# Is nested SelectMany supported in Linq to Entities?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

Is nested `GroupBy()` then flatten allowed in SQL? or available via ling-to-sql or the entity framework?  Currently, I need to perform a retrieve in the middle of the query to make it work:

```
var query = (
    from s in Prices
    group s by new { s.P1, s.P2 } into FirstGroups
    select FirstGroups
)
.ToList() // without it, exception is thrown
.SelectMany(g1 =>   
    g1.GroupBy(i => i.P3).OrderBy(i => i.Key).Take(2)
      .SelectMany((g2, index) => g.Select(j => new
        {
            P1 = g1.Key.P1,
            P2 = g1.Key.P2,
            Index = index,
            P3 = g2.P3,
            P4 = j.P4,
        }));
});
```

Single SelectMany works.  Nested expressed this way doesn't work in linq-to-sql.  My question is does l2s support it at all?  if yes, how to write the query.  if not, does any other linq to db technology support it, for example, the new entity framework?

Answer (score 0):

Grouping and then flattening the results is the same as simply ordering on that value.

Comment: I am grouping twice and did a Take after the nested GroupBy.  It's more complicated than ordering.